# Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error

Tags: python, image, file-writing, file-not-found

Want to name a file with open function, but error occur.
Can not figure out what is the problem, with just img_name = 'image1' everything is OK.
Thanks

```
img_name = f'{id_}/image-{img_num}.jpg'
with open(img_name, 'wb') as img_file:
```

Answer (score 3):

When writing a file in python, the folder you write to (here `{id_}`) must exist.

You can use `os.makedirs(folder)` if it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: but why there is no error when I set img_name = 'image1" for example?

Comment: Good question. If you say "image1", that is just a filename, not a folder. So python will just place image1 in your current working directory.

Comment: Look img_name = f'{id_}/image-{img_num}.jpg' this line generates '7566692/image-1.jpg' file name and as you mentioned the file with such name must be placed in current working directory, but there is an error.